# Switch programmatically between fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment

I started writing an app with android studio's navigation drawer template.

I can't figure out how to properly switch between fragments.

I tried 2 ways :

1. By replacing fragments

```
switchFragmentsButton.setOnClickListener {
    requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.commit {
        setReorderingAllowed(false)
        addToBackStack(null)
        replace<SlideshowFragment>(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
    }
}
```

Result is terrible, old fragment is visible behind new fragment and in drawer menu it not change current menu.

2. By navigating with navHostFragment

```
<action 
    android:id="@+id/action_to_another_fragment"
    app:destination="@+id/nav_gallery" />
```

- 

```
val navHostFragment = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main) as NavHostFragment
val navController = navHostFragment.navController
navController.navigate(R.id.action_to_another_fragment)
```

Result is better, navigation is done in drawer menu, everything seems perfect except i can't go to source fragment anymore through drawer menu.
Clicking on menu item results in nothing.

What do i do wrong please ?